# Is it a good thing to starting service in new thread from activity

Tags: android, service, locationlistener

```
new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run () {
                Intent firstServiceIntent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MyService.class);
            }
        }).start();
```

I have to perform background location updates in the service. I've used LocationListner in the service and it calls onLocationChanged() frequently, which can block my UI thread. If I use create thread in onLocationChanged(), every-time this method is called a new thread would be spawned. So, I'm thinking of creating the entire service in new thread instead of creating thread in onLocationChanged() . Is this a good solution or what should be the best way? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: When I tried Thread.currentThread().getId() in the activity and the service, both resulted in the same id. And so I figured out that they are working in the same thread., which I do not want. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: which service are you using ?? `IntentService` ??

Comment: `Service` is a component so why put extra overhead to start it from a background thread ?  Ultimately `Service` will run on Main thread.

Comment: Launching a service in a thread doesn't run the service in a thread.  So there's no point to this.

Comment: @GabeSechan this makes sense.. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want your service to run on a background thread, then you have two options:

1. Use an `IntentService` which automatically is run on a background thread by the Android OS. Everything you do inside the `IntentService` will be run on the background thread. You don't need to do any threading.
2. Use a standard Android `Service` and instantiate a `new Thread()` inside the service where you want to perform the work. The standard Android `Service` is run by default on the main thread so it will block your UI. That's why you have to handle the threading yourself.

More information here:
[Android Services](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)

Answer (score 1):

A service runs in the main thread of its hosting process; the service does not create its own thread and does not run in a separate process unless you specify otherwise.

However, launching a service from a different thread looks ugly. You can create a new thread inside the service.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `IntentService` component of android , it will automatically take care of your background processing in `onHandleIntent(...)`  you can try...

```
  class YourService extends IntentService
```

[IntentService](https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service.html)

else if you use `Service` like

```
  class YourService extends Service
```

you can use your *custom thread* in `onCreate()`

**ELSE**

The service will run in the `MainThread`

[Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)